# Data Not Showing from database to Spinner

Tags: android, database, spinner

I am developing a small app in which i have to used a spinner with database. I am using

```
   spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
     loadSpinnerData();
```

My loadSpinnerData() is below

```
        private void loadSpinnerData() {
        // database handler
     AndroidContext.setContext(this);

        sqlitedatabase_obj = DatabaseHelper.getInstance().getDb();

        // Spinner Drop down elements
         DatabaseHelper db = new DatabaseHelper(getApplicationContext());
        List<String> lables = db.getAllLabels();

        // Creating adapter for spinner
        ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, lables);

        // Drop down layout style - list view with radio button
        dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

        // attaching data adapter to spinner
        spinner.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
    }
```

getAllLabels is define in DatabaseHelper class

```
                public List<String> getAllLabels(){
    List<String> labels = new ArrayList<String>();

    // Select All Query
    String selectQuery = "SELECT _id, product_name  FROM list_create WHERE _id = ?";

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

    // looping through all rows and adding to list
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            labels.add(cursor.getString(1));
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }

    // closing connection
    cursor.close();
    db.close();

    // returning lables
    return labels;
}
```

I want to show dynamic spinner with data from database. But i am not able to populate data from data base even i did not get and exception or error .

Comment: SELECT _id, product_name  FROM list_create WHERE _id = ? here you are making mistake i think. Provide some id if you want to get data for particular id or use * for getting all the data. Mostly your problem will be resolved.

Comment: If you want to retrieve all labels, then remove the where clause from the query. or else fix that by supplying selectionArgs while execution(i.e, in db.rawQuery(...)).  everything else looks fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`WHERE _id = ?`

that might be your issue. It is looking for rows where your `_id` column equals that character (normally it contains unique long values). I have the idea that you wanted a less specific query. try adjusting it and then logging your cursor count to verify that anything is actually being returned: `cursor.getCount();`